# Discord.js and http listener with GET request

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I have a windows application that receives **http GET requests**. for example, send a message to a user or send a message to a chat channel. But I can't create a voice or text channel on the server by means Discord.js. I turn to the forum from despair. Please help

**So the system is implemented:**

```
Windows App (for Users) <==> Windows Server for App <==> Discord Bot (Server) <==> MYSQL
```

For example, send a message:

```
if (req.params.type === 'sendMessage')
  {
    channelName = req.params.channel;
    message = req.params.message;
    channel = bot.channels.find('name', channelName);
    channel.send(message);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Maybe someone will help. Topic closed.

`bot.rest.methods.createChannel('424511917596606464' ,nameChannel, "text", 0, 0);` (snowflake server, nameChannel, voice or text or category, overwrites, reason)

const bot = new Discord.Client();